# MySQL con php LIKE y PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hola espero que estén muy bien, esta mi primera introducción con  PDO y se me hizo super interesante, a raíz de esto he tenido algunas dudas en cuanto a los `SELECT` que espero me puedan ayudar de momento tengo esto así:

```
SELECT id FROM tabla WHERE campo LIKE ?
```

ó

```
SELECT id FROM tabla WHERE campo LIKE ?​ OR campo2 LIKE CONTACT ('%',:buscar,'%')
```

ó

```
`SELECT id FROM tabla WHERE campo LIKE %?%`  (o que pasa si aveces quiero consultar dos campos, tres o según decida el usuario, desde el formulario de búsqueda)​
```

y he visto muchas variantes en Internet pero nada conciso me gustaría saber su opinión o la mejor manera de realizar dicha consulta.

Comment: Dime que buscas basicamente en tu select like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola te explico basándome en el sitio oficial de MySQL, todo depende de tu necesidad.

Estos son ejemplos a una tabla de (pets)

Con esta consulta puedes encontrar los nombres (name) que comienzen por la letra b.

```
SELECT * FROM pet WHERE name LIKE 'b%';
+--------+--------+---------+------+------------+------------+
| name   | owner  | species | sex  | birth      | death      |
+--------+--------+---------+------+------------+------------+
| Buffy  | Harold | dog     | f    | 1989-05-13 | NULL       |
| Bowser | Diane  | dog     | m    | 1989-08-31 | 1995-07-29 |
+--------+--------+---------+------+------------+------------+
```

> Actualización

Consulta en PDO:

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM pet WHERE column LIKE ?');
$query->bindValue(1, "%fy", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
```

Con la siguiente consulta puedes buscar con los nombres que terminen con la letra o palabra fy

```
SELECT * FROM pet WHERE name LIKE '%fy';
+--------+--------+---------+------+------------+-------+
| name   | owner  | species | sex  | birth      | death |
+--------+--------+---------+------+------------+-------+
| Fluffy | Harold | cat     | f    | 1993-02-04 | NULL  |
| Buffy  | Harold | dog     | f    | 1989-05-13 | NULL  |
+--------+--------+---------+------+------------+-------+
```

La siguiente consulta es para buscar los nombres que contengan en alguna parte la letra W:

```
SELECT * FROM pet WHERE name LIKE '%w%';
+----------+-------+---------+------+------------+------------+
| name     | owner | species | sex  | birth      | death      |
+----------+-------+---------+------+------------+------------+
| Claws    | Gwen  | cat     | m    | 1994-03-17 | NULL       |
| Bowser   | Diane | dog     | m    | 1989-08-31 | 1995-07-29 |
| Whistler | Gwen  | bird    | NULL | 1997-12-09 | NULL       |
+----------+-------+---------+------+------------+------------+
```

Para encontrar nombres que contengan exactamente un numero exacto de caracteres, use instancias del `_` carácter de patrón, por ejemplo que tenga solo 5 caracteres:

```
SELECT * FROM pet WHERE name LIKE '_____';
+-------+--------+---------+------+------------+-------+
| name  | owner  | species | sex  | birth      | death |
+-------+--------+---------+------+------------+-------+
| Claws | Gwen   | cat     | m    | 1994-03-17 | NULL  |
| Buffy | Harold | dog     | f    | 1989-05-13 | NULL  |
+-------+--------+---------+------+------------+-------+
```

Como te dije todo depende de tu necesidad, sin embargo aqui te dejo la documentacion oficial:

Link: [Coincidencia de patrones](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html)

Comment: Se ve muy bien la concidencia, te agradezco

Comment: Ok,  y si te lo agradecería

Comment: Listo he actualizado mi respuesta, puse la query debajo del primer ejemplo, no olvides el check amigo ;)